# Return first entry in table for every row given a specifc column sort order

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a table with three columns, hostname, address, and virtual. The address column is unique, but a host can have up to two address entries, one virtual and one non-virtual. In other words, the hostname and virtual column pair are also unique. I want to produce a result set that contains one address entry for a host giving priority to the virtual address. For example, I have:

```
hostname | address | virtual
---------+---------+--------
first    | 1.1.1.1 | TRUE
first    | 1.1.1.2 | FALSE
second   | 1.1.2.1 | FALSE
third    | 1.1.3.1 | TRUE
fourth   | 1.1.4.2 | FALSE
fourth   | 1.1.4.1 | TRUE
```

The query should return the results:

```
hostname | address 
---------+--------
first    | 1.1.1.1
second   | 1.1.2.1
third    | 1.1.3.1
fourth   | 1.1.4.1
```

Which is the virtual address for every host, and the non-virtual address for hosts lacking a virtual address. The closest I've come is asking for one specific host:

```
SELECT hostname, address
FROM system
WHERE hostname = 'first'
ORDER BY virtual DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT 1;
```

Which gives this:

```
hostname | address 
---------+--------
first    | 1.1.1.1
```

I would like to get this for every host in the table with a single query if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a `RANK` function. It would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT hostname, address
    , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY hostname ORDER BY virtual DESC NULLS LAST) AS rk
    FROM system
)
WHERE rk = 1
```

This is a portable solution that also works in Oracle and SQL Server.

Comment: `row_number()` would achieve the same here, a bit cheaper. But `DISTINCT ON` will be substantially faster for the use case (just 1 or 2 rows per `hostname`).

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres, the simplest way is `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (hostname) hostname, address
FROM system
ORDER BY hostname, virtual DESC NULLS LAST
```